# Error al generar Scaffolding en ASP.Net

Tags: vs

Estaba tratando de generar un controlador con la ayuda del generador de código VS, pero cuando hago clic en "Agregar", aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedas ayudar a resolver mi duda...